# GNU Fortran compiler optimisation flags for Ivy Bridge architecture

Tags: fortran, gnu, gfortran, compiler-flags

May I please ask for your suggestions on the GNU Fortran compiler (v6.3.0) flags to optimise the code for the Ivy Bridge architecture (Intel Xeon CPU E5-2697v2 Ivy Bridge @ 2.7 GHz)?

At the moment I’m compiling the code with the following flags:

```
-O3 -march=ivybridge -mtune=ivybridge -ffast-math -mavx -m64 -w
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use intrinsics specific to Ivy bridge, Sandy bridge flag os sufficient.  I expect you should find some advantage by setting additionally `-funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=2`

Sometimes `-O2 -ftree-vectorize` will work out better than `-O3`.
If you have complex data type you will want to check vs. `-fno-cx-limited-range` as the default of `-ffast-math` may be too aggressive.

Comment: With gfortran (but not gcc) max-unroll-times=4 should often come out slightly better than 2.